# MySql: get at least N elements

Tags: mysql

How to express in a MySQL query: "get all new elements but at least N elements".

I'll try to explain better. I want to know how to make a query if I have a product list [product, price, date, new] and I want to show the user all new elements, but if there are less than N elements (e.g. 5) show also the last items. If could think in a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE new='1' ORDER BY date DESC
```

but this just returns all new elements and this:

```
SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE new='0' ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 5
```

just returns the minimum elements required.

Some examples:

- If the table contains 4 new items, the query should return 4 new items and the latest non-new item
- If the table contains 7 new items, the query should return just the 7 new items
- If the table contains 1 new item, the query should return the new item and 4 non-new items.

Comment: How does the `new` field differentiate from the `date` field? If you ordered by the date and limit the results to 5, won't that get you the results you were looking for anyway? Even if the 5th element in the results is not "new", it would still be the latest non-new item, no?

Comment: Not possible with a LIMIT query. The limit values must be constants, or variables - you cannot dynamically fill in the limit as the query runs. You'll need to do some client-side massaging.

Comment: @logan: it'd only return 5 items, though, even if there are 7 new/0 old items to display.

Comment: @Logan: No, because new is a flag that the admin can set manually to any item.

Comment: I see. Unfortunately Marc is right, this is impossible to do with a MySQL query (that I know of). You would have to do something else, like query all of the new items, count them, and check if the number of rows returned is less than 5. If it is, execute another query to non-new items and limit that to 5 minus the number of rows returned in the earlier query.

Comment: Please take a look at my answer. Maybe that will make it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use UNION to combine two result sets.

```
(
    SELECT *
    FROM `products`
    WHERE new = '1'
)
UNION
(
    SELECT *
    FROM `products`
    ORDER BY new DESC, date DESC
    LIMIT 5
) T1
ORDER BY new DESC, date DESC
```

- The first part of the UNION returns all the new items.
- The second part of the UNION returns the first five new items, or if there are fewer than 5 items, all the new items and then first 5-n old items.
- The UNION removes any duplicates in the result set.

Note that this assumes that there is a unique key defined on any column or combination of columns in your table (for example, if your table has a primary key this should work).

Comment: This is what I thought at first too. However this will limit to only 5 results even if there are more than 5 new items to display.

Comment: The problem is that it will output 5 old results even if there are some new results.

Comment: @Karolis: No. It will only output *up to 5* old rows. If there are five or more new rows, *no* old rows will be returned.

Comment: That is! Just removed SELECT * FROM because it is not necessary and produces an ugly "Every derived table must have its own alias" :)

Comment: @RedFilter: What specifically doesn't match the spec? My query will return the 7 new items only.

Answer (score 1):

Order also by `new`, not only `date`

```
SELECT * FROM `products` ORDER BY new, date DESC
```

Comment: +1 Cuz we thought of the same thing -- but don't forget the limit 5.

Comment: @Marvo why limit? It says all new elements but not fewer than five elements. This query satisfies both requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best you can do is a `UNION` of two selects: 1) all new items and 2) the minimum number of additional items. Then decide in your application logic which rows to display. SQL doesn't provide syntax to do what you're asking.

*EDIT:* Actually, perhaps it is possible to do this using user-defined variables. It's probably less work (for the MySQL server) just to do the `UNION` and have done with it, though.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *, @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rownum
FROM products, (SELECT @rownum := 0) AS vars
ORDER BY new DESC, date DESC
HAVING rownum <= 5 OR new = 1
```

Comment: I've trying this, but I can't get it to return 5 items when there are less than 5 new items

Answer (score 0):

`select * from products order by new desc, date desc limit 5`

This assumes that the "new" column will only have values of 1 or 0 in it.

Comment: But if there are 7 new items, it will return only 5! :)

Answer (score 0):

Pseudocode:

```
CREATE STOREPROCEDURO
(
  @howMany INT
)

Declare @nNew INT

Declare @nOld INT

SET @nNew = (select count(*) from table where new = 1 order by date desc)

set @nOld = (select count(*) from table where old = 1 order by date desc)

set @nOld = @howMany - @nNew

if (@nOld < 0)
begin
  @nOld = 0
end

(select top (@nNew) * from table where new = 1 order by date desc)
union
(select top (@nOld) * from table where new = 0 order by date desc)
</code>
```